# Jquery dynamically created form not posting in FireFox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a form for each line item in a list. This html is loaded via ajax and set to a modal

```
 <%foreach (var item in group.GroupItems){%>
       <form id="bomItemForm<%=item.BomPartNumber %>" >
           <%-- ... form fields --%>
           <input type="submit" value="Add"  />
       </form>
 <%} %>
```

then my jquery has this

```
$(document).on("submit", "[id^='bomItemForm']", function() {
    alert("hit it");
});
```

this works in IE, and Chrome but not in firefox. Nothing happens at all.
I have tried with .live and just using the selector. any ideas what could make fire fox not like this?
I ommitted the form field for simplicity sake. I am just trying to intercept the form post. As mentioned works great in IE and Chrome. not in firefox.
Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's MVC but he aren't using Razor like render engine, razor starts with MVC 3

Answer (score 1):

how about a "submit" ?

```
$("[id^='bomItemForm']").submit(function(event) {
  alert('hit it'+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: I tried this with the same result. Works in all browsers except Fire Fox.

Comment: firefox  13.0 is the one I am trying this on

Comment: Are you using the "submit" to name attribute?

Comment: 'submit' is not being used as any form attribute